# How can I refresh a tableview after a segue occurs?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, uistoryboardsegue

I have a button placed inside of a view controller that triggers a segue. After my data (in this case, pickerview data) is passed from my view controller to a tableview via the segue, I'd like to refresh the tableview (located in the segue's destination controller). How can I do this? See code below.

```
- (IBAction)buttonpressed:(UIButton *)sender {

        NSLog(@"Button Pushed!");

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pickerGo"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        ViewController *strainTableView = [(UINavigationController *)[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

        NSPredicate *ailmentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ailment contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];

        NSPredicate *actionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Action contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

        NSPredicate *ingestPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Ingestion contains[cd] %@", [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];


        NSCompoundPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ailmentPredicate,actionPredicate,ingestPredicate, nil]];

        pickerResults = [Strains filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];


        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [strainTableView setSearchResults: pickerResults];


    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `setSearchResults:` ne a good candidate for a place from where to refresh the table view?

Comment: Yes, but when I add in the reloadData bit, it keeps telling me that tableView can't be found on this view controller (even though I've imported the TableViewController.h file).

Comment: The call of `reloadData` should happen inside the `setSearchResults:` method of the destination view controller, which owns the table view.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the cast to `(UINavigationController *)` is unnecessary, you can rewrite it as `ViewController *strainTableView = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`

Comment: strainTableView isn't on screen when you set the picker results is it? If it isn't then that is your problem. You cannot refresh a view that is not loaded yet, and it will not be loaded until the prepareForSegue is completed. If this is the case (which is just a guess at this point) then you should do it in `strainTableView`'s `viewDidLoad` unless I am misunderstanding part of the question.